# react context as component prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

everyone. trying to make a react component expecting context with one required property (I don't care about other properties in context) passed via props. so far ended up with this:

```
interface IContextWithData {
    data: Record<any,any>;
}

interface IProps<T extends IContextWithData> {
    context: React.Context<T>;
}

const Component: React.FC<IProps<any>> = (props: IProps<any>): JSX.Element => {  
  const { data } = React.useContext(props.context);
  ...
}
```

which compiles, but I don't want to fallback to `any` as it won't make `data` property required for passed context objects

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic function.

```
const Component = <C extends IContextWithData, T extends IProps<C>>(props: T): JSX.Element => {  
  const { data } = React.useContext(props.context);
  ...
}
```

You wont actually need to pass the type args to the component in the consumer, as it will be inferred by TS automatically.

BTW, what you are doing seems a little odd. Whats your use case for passing the context *type* as a prop?

Comment: I've wanted to use the component in different components, each one having their own context with (possibly) different `data`. I understand my approach is not the best one but been always fighting with types a lot - next time I'd rather re-think how to do solve the problem in a different way

Comment: your solution does not work for me, getting error, e.g. `Type 'Provider<C1Ctx>' is not assignable to type 'Provider<IContextWithData>'` when trying to pass value to `context` prop, e.g.:

interface C1Ctx extends IContextWithData {
  prop1: any;
}

const C1: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const ctxValues: C1Ctx = {
    prop1: 'test',
    data: {a:1},
  };
  const ctx = React.createContext(ctxValues);
  return <Component context={ctx} />;
}

Comment: `const Component = <T extends IContextWithData>(props: IProps<T>): JSX.Element =>` does the trick